# White border on webpage

Tags: html, kotlin-js, jetbrains-compose, compose-web

My website is displaying an undesired white border for all my components, even when using default configs:

Main.kt

```
fun main() {
    renderComposable("root") {
        Div({ style { height(300.px); backgroundColor(blue) } }) { }
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="MyApp.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

renders

[image]

Can you notice the white border around the blue background?

Why does this happen? How to remove this white border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to the [default margin for the body tag being 8px](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp).

This means that the default body component is rendered with an 8px margin, which is what you're seeing as a "white border".

To remove it, you simply have to adjust your `body` tag style. This can be done at your `index.html` file, where you declare your body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My Website</title>
    </head>

    <body style="margin: 0">

        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="MyApp.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```